# MPC Playlist not loading last played media

Tags: playlists, media-player-classic

I have this problem in which I created a playlist with some video files and saved the mpcpl file.

Now when I open this mpcpl file, instead of playing from the last position of the last running video, it always starts from the first file and initial position.

I've enabled all the options in History of Player section in Options like above screenshot.

So, what's the use of creating the playlist if I've to remember which video I've to open in that playlist? Instead, again, the moment I open that mpcpl file it should play the last played video (somewhere in the middle for example) with its last played position!

Comment: The screenshot is missing

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking the developers. There is no question here we can answer.

Comment: @Kai create a new issue here https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/issues